# EF: Query quite slow on first execution

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, asp.net-core

We are using EF Core 1.1, in an ASP.NET Core app, where the following LINQ query takes about 45 seconds to a minute on its first execution. After the first execution, the subsequent executions seem to work fine.

**Question**: How can we improve the performance of this query. User waiting for about 45 seconds or more gives him/her an impression that probably the ASP.NET page displaying the query is broken and user moves on to another page:

```
var lstProjects = _context.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectYear == FY && p.User == User_Name).OrderBy(p => p.ProjectNumber).ToList();
```

**Execution Plan in SQL Server Query Editor**: The table has 24 columns one of which is of type varchar(255), four are of type varchar(75). Others are of types int, smalldatetime, bit etc. All of the columns are needed in the query. But the `WHERE` clause filters the data to return about 35 rows out of about 26,000.

[image]

**More details on Execution Plan**

[image]

Comment: What indices are you using? Where is the clustered index? Is it an autonumber Id field, or the ProjectNumber field?

Comment: @PlayDeezGames Entire app is based on `EF`, no Stored Procs or Views. clustered index is on identity column (auto number).

Comment: @Igor In the `Execution Plan` section of my post, I've provided details of the table. There is no binary data, but some text data (not huge text - maybe 8 to 10 lines in some cases). Client thinks since there are at most 35 records to display, there should not be any paging.

Comment: I read the image wrong, I thought there were 25K rows being returned.

Comment: Reading 26,000 rows of 470 bytes shouldn't take 45 seconds unless you are encountering blocking. Why do you believe the issue is with SQL Server rather than Elsewhere?

Comment: @nam do you know if this is the first call to the database?  Asked a different way, is this first time you are returning a result from the C# _context object. If so app may be taking most of that time to establish the connection.

Comment: @chris No this is not the first time app is returning a result from  `C# _context object`. After reading your comment, I started SQL profiler and ran the app. The profiler shows there are three small `Select` queries that run before the query in question. Those 3 queries are quite small that return data for three lookup tables.

Comment: part of the issue is that you are relying solely on EF for the schema. CodeFirst is fine for setting up an initial schema, but you still need to add indexing based on the high-traffic areas of the app. The index scan is just across the PK which is really doing nothing more than a table scan. I'm curious that the execution plan did not come back with a suggestion, though that's probably because you may not have changed parameters between runs. Creating an index on ProjectYear+Username would see performance improve. CodeFirst != don't need indexing / DBA. :)

Comment: @StevePy Steve, for the benefits of other readers, you may want to write your comment (with any additional info if you like) in a response as I found it helpful. I'll mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated comment to answer.

When using Code First there still needs to be a consideration for indexing based on the common queries run in high-traffic areas of the application. The index scan across the PK amounts to little more than a table scan so an index across the Project Year + UserName would give a boost in performance and should be considered if this is expected to be used a bit or is performance sensitive.  Regardless of DB First or Code First, developers need to consider profiler results against the database in order to optimize indexing based on realistic usage.  Normally the execution plan will return back suggestions for indexing. Index suggestions should appear just below the SQL statement in the execution plan. From the screen shot it isn't clear whether one was suggested or not, as there might have been a scrollbar to the right of the SQL under the pop-up stats.

In cases where a query is returning slow results but no suggestions, try re-running the query with altered parameters with the execution plan to exclude SQL from picking up pre-compiled queries.

Comment: I'd tend to go username + project year as that will help queries just on usernames

Comment: @StevePy I found your response to be very educational. Thanks for sharing your experience/knowledge. The screenshot did miss the bottom part of the execution plan - and that may have included execution plan output suggestions you are referring to.